# Bug with clamp.js - a.lastChild is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, clamp

I am trying to use clamp.js but I get a bug right away. This is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>

        <script src="js/plugin/clamp.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="test" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
            AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA AAAAAA 
        </div>

        <script>
            var e = document.getElementById("test");
            var r = $clamp(e, {clamp: 1, useNativeClamp :false});
            console.log(r);
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

And I get `TypeError: a.lastChild is null[Learn More]` in firefox, and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null` in chrome.

This is the file I am using [clamp.min.js](https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js/blob/master/clamp.min.js).

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: The issue is with `useNativeClamp :false`. After removing this option, it works.

Comment: If I remove it, it partially works in chrome, but same error in firefox. Also in chrome it doesn't respect the height I give it, it just uses the 200px still. The above should make it 1 line, but its still multiline.